# Fastest way to find first element within an interval

Tags: c#

I have a List of objects from the class below. This list has more than 150,000 records.

```
public class CoordsImportViewModel
    {
        public decimal? xAxis { get; set; }
        public decimal? yAxis { get; set; }
        public long? unixEpochDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I use the following code several times to find some specific records and as you can imagine it takes a lot of time.

```
coordsList.Where(x => x.unixEpochDate >= timeStamp && x.unixEpochDate < timeStamp + interval)
                                         .Select(x => new {
                                             x,
                                             y,
                                         }).FirstOrDefault()
```

Is there any way to optimize this?

EDIT: The list is sorted by unixEpochDate.

Comment: I believe this is a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: Finding something in an arbitrary list of 150 000 elements is tough. Doing the same in a *sorted* list of the same size takes 18 tries at worst. (Unfortunately the Framework's built-in binary searches don't take predicates, they only search for exact matches.)

Comment: Am I understanding your intent correctly, you want to filter a collection, then convert into a simple object representing x and y, but only grab the first newly created one?  Couldn't you do `FirstOrDefault` or `First` then simply `Select` into a new x and y?

Comment: Ok, so the list is sorted, then binary search should do. And of course no (standard) LINQ, you can safely remove that tag from the question (if you really care about the performance in this scenario).

Comment: I use the Where to find the records, then Select to pick only two attributes and I choose the first, if it exists. That record is then aded to another list.

Comment: There's an overload of `List<T>.BinarySearch` that takes an `IComparer<T>`.  Using that you can search for `timestamp` to get it's exact position (positive result) or the location of the next item that would be after it in a sorted list (negative bitwise compliment).  If negative you can check if the next entry is within the `interval`.  This all depends on the list being sorted by the time stamp.

Comment: @juharr Totally spaced that, that would be a nice approach.

Comment: Do you really need optimization for that? I filled the list with 150 000 items. It took 2ms to search with your code on my machine.

193 ms for the list of 15 million elements where first resulting element was at 10 millionth index.

32 GB RAM, i5-7600K CPU (3.8 GHz).

Comment: @msmolcic The problem is that I do that query more than 150 000 times.

Comment: @MarcusSilveres Try changing the logic, run queries in parallel, delegate it to background threads, run it on a super computer or run them all at once on multiple AWS lambda's. Sorry, but there's really nothing to optimize here, you need to look at the alternate way to do it, maybe some of these alternatives I mentioned suits your case, I don't know what you're doing exactly.